# Default value doesn't work in SQLAlchemy + PostgreSQL + aiopg + psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, default, psycopg2

I've found an unexpected behavior in SQLAlchemy. I'm using the following versions:

- **SQLAlchemy** (0.9.8)
- **PostgreSQL** (9.3.5)
- **psycopg2** (2.5.4)
- **aiopg** (0.5.1)

This is the table definition for the example:

```
import asyncio
from aiopg.sa import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import (
  MetaData,
  Column,
  Integer,
  Table,
  String,
)
metadata = MetaData()

users = Table('users', metadata,
  Column('id_user', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
  Column('name', String(20), unique=True),
  Column('age', Integer, nullable=False, default=0),
)
```

Now if I try to execute a simple insert to the table just populating the ***id_user*** and ***name***, the column ***age*** should be auto-generated right? Lets see...

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def go():
  engine = yield from create_engine('postgresql://USER@localhost/DB')
  data = {'id_user':1, 'name':'Jimmy' }
  stmt = users.insert(values=data, inline=False)
  with (yield from engine) as conn:
    result = yield from conn.execute(stmt)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(go())
```

This is the resulting statement with the corresponding error:

```
INSERT INTO users (id_user, name, age) VALUES (1, 'Jimmy', null);

psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "age" violates not-null constraint
```

I didn't provide the **age** column, so where is that **age = null** value coming from? I was expecting something like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (id_user, name) VALUES (1, 'Jimmy');
```

Or if the ***default*** flag actually works should be:

```
INSERT INTO users (id_user, name, Age) VALUES (1, 'Jimmy', 0);
```

Could you put some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been confirmed has an **aiopg** bug. Seems like at the moment it's ignoring the `default` argument on data manipulation.

I've fixed the issue using `server_default` instead:

```
users = Table('users', metadata,
          Column('id_user', Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False),
          Column('name', String(20), unique=True),
          Column('age', Integer, nullable=False, server_default='0'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `inline=True` in your insert. This turns off 'pre-execution'.
Docs are a bit cryptic on what exactly this 'pre-execution' entails, but they mentions default parameters:

```
    :param inline:
      if True, SQL defaults present on :class:`.Column` objects via
      the ``default`` keyword will be compiled 'inline' into the statement
      and not pre-executed.  This means that their values will not
      be available in the dictionary returned from
      :meth:`.ResultProxy.last_updated_params`.
```

This piece of docstring is from Update class, but they have a shared behavior with Insert.

Besides, that's the only way they test it: 
https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_0_9/test/sql/test_insert.py#L385

Comment: Sorry I forgot saying that I was using **aiopg**. I've followed your advice using `users.insert(values=data, inline=False)` but still getting the error:
`null value in column "age" violates not-null constraint`